# Mui Select multiple unexpected option list rerender

Tags: select, material-ui

I am trying to understand the cause of the whole list re-render when selecting/deselecting an option.

https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-select-8wjpm3
Please see working sandbox.

I've tried manipulating with option keys but didn't help. Unfortunately the only way of this type of select UI working is with native .